# How to remove square bracket and store that data in dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have below data in List:

```
[{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
      'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
      'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
      'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
      'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
```

But I want to remove outer square bracket and store that remaining data in dictionary.
how should i do it in python.
**EDITED:**

```
[{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
      'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
      'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
      'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
      'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
      
      {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': M, 
       'Clear': DONE,
      'Computed': None, 'impact': 256,
      'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
      'Object': None, 'TicketId': 579, 'service': 670,
      'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
```

Here is list of dictionary So how should i return one by one dictionary in other function of python.(its may many dictionary in list, so how we iterate and return in other function)

**tried code:**

```
def data():
    [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
          'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
          'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
          'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
          'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}, 
          
          {'Details': [], 'age': 56, 'his': F, 
           'Clear': DONE,
          'Computed': None, 'impact': 234,
          'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
          'Object': None, 'TicketId': 456, 'service': 650,
          'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
    for i in jData:
        print("returning i")
        return i

def return_data():
    i = data()
    print("returned i", i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return_data()
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: It looks like you already have a dictionary. try: `mydict = data[0]`

Comment: The square bracket is how the list appears. Are you just wanting to modify appearance?

Comment: No. The outer bracket signifies a list, but the curly braces within it indicate a dictionary is the list item.

Answer (score 2):

you already have dictionary as first element in list just use below code:

```
list1 = [{'Details': [], 'age': None, 'his': F, 'Clear': None,
      'Computed': None, 'impact': 0,
      'Status': None, 'ID': None, 'bel': None,
      'Object': None, 'TicketId': 123, 'service': 257,
      'Status': 'NOT', 'Name': 'xyz'}]
d1 = list1[0]
```